# Creating an new field from mathematically manipulating values in other fields

Tags: mysql

Bit of a newbie here.  I'm currently working on a MySQL table that lists the details for different cars.  I need a new field that is built up of the information from three other fields.  So I have 'Acceleration', 'Speed' and 'Braking' which all contain double digit integers that are averaged out to another field I want to call 'Average'.

The logic being 'Acceleration'+'Speed'+'Braking'/3

I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax to do this.  I do specifically need this to be a field as I need those values to show up on other queries.  I know a SELECT query can get the result values I need, but how to I conduct those values to a permanent field on that table?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: Can you post your table structure and sample data?

Comment: you need to add Average Filed and value of the filed is 'Acceleration'+'Speed'+'Braking'/3 .and  please give some sample output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, you'd need to alter the table schema to define the new column:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN Average FLOAT;
   ```
2. Next, update the table to set the values:

   ```
   UPDATE my_table SET Average = (Acceleration + Speed + Braking) / 3;
   ```
3. Consider how to correctly set `Average` for newly inserted/updated data.  Perhaps use triggers:

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER calc_average_ins AFTER INSERT ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
   SET NEW.Average = (NEW.Acceleration + NEW.Speed + NEW.Braking) / 3;

   CREATE TRIGGER calc_average_upd AFTER UPDATE ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
   SET NEW.Average = (NEW.Acceleration + NEW.Speed + NEW.Braking) / 3;
   ```

You might want to consider instead introducing this column in a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/views.html), to create the averages as required, on-the-fly, and thereby preventing it from becoming desynchronised from the underlying data values (but note you no longer achieve the performance benefit of having the values cached):

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT *, (Acceleration + Speed + Braking) / 3 AS Average FROM my_table;
```

Finally, note that your average has no physical meaning in the real world (what would be its units?): a more meaningful metric may or may not be more suitable to your needs.

Comment: Fantastic answer!  Yeah, I'm aware of this average having no real application.  Think of it as a "rating" value that considers these aspects of the car to give a /100 score if you will.  The Triggers would be the next question I would have had so you're one step ahead of me there too.  Thank you again for this help, it's going to help a lot.